# Cannot obtain the output of intermediate sub-model layers with tf2.0/keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Say we use TensorFlow r2.0 and say we want to use sub-models in Keras, so we have a model **A** like this:

```py
def create_model_A(in_num_units, name):
    x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(in_num_units))
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_num_units, activation='relu')(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_num_units, activation='relu')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = x + y
    return tf.keras.Model(x, y, name=name)
```

and model **B** that makes use of model **A**:

```py
def create_model_B(in_num_units):
    x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(in_num_units))
    y = create_model_A(x.shape[-1], name='A_1')(x)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_num_units // 2, name='downsize_1')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = create_model_A(y.shape[-1], name='A_2')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_num_units // 2, name='downsize_2')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = create_model_A(y.shape[-1], name='A_3')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(in_num_units // 2, name='downsize_3')(y)
    y = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = create_model_A(y.shape[-1], name='A_4')(y)
    return tf.keras.Model(x, y)
```

This works like a charm. We can instantiate a model **B** like this:

```py
num_in_units = 500
model = create_model_B(num_in_units) # Works!
```

And benefit from all the advantages of a tf.keras.Model. But, the problem arises when we want to obtain the result of an intermediate layer that is of sub-model **A**. If the layer is part of model **B**, everything works:

```py
inter_model_1 = tf.keras.Model(
    model.input, model.get_layer('downsize_1').output) # Works!
```

But if the layer is of sub-model A, it crashes with a `ValueError`. This command:

```py
inter_model_2 = tf.keras.Model(
    model.input, model.get_layer('A_3').output) # Does not work!
```

Gives:

```sh
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_4:0", shape=(None, 250), dtype=float32) at layer "input_4". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I'm not sure I understand all the inside mechanics of keras. But what I understand when I dove in the source code, is that sub-models used this way have two input tensors object created. They can be printed like this:

```py
print([n.input_tensors.name for n in model.get_layer('A_3').inbound_nodes])
```

```sh
['input_4:0', 'batch_normalization_5/Identity:0']
```

One is the sub-model `tf.keras.Input` and the other one is the input linked to the top-model.

When building a new model from a top-model **B** input tensor to a top-model **B** output tensor, the path in the graph seems to correctly pass by the `'batch_normalization_5'` input and both tensors are correctly connected in the graph.

However, when trying to link a top-model **B** input tensor to a sub-model **A** output tensor, the output tensors seems to be connected to the sub-model `tf.keras.Input` and both tensors are disconnected.

A solution I found at the moment is to use the top-model version of the tensor `model.get_layer('A_3').output`:

```py
model.get_layer('A_3')._outbound_nodes[0].input_tensors
```

But this seems overcomplicated and not clean... In addition, it does not let us make use of the layers inside model **A**.

I wonder if someone could give me some precision on this particular `tf.keras` behavior. Am I right to do so? Is this the intended behavior? Is this a bug? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

just change `output` to `get_output_at(0)`

```
inter_model_2 = tf.keras.Model(
    model.input, model.get_layer('A_3').get_output_at(0))
```

Comment: It works. Can you explain why does it work? Thank you.

Comment: @ ldavid  if `A_3 ` layer has only one inbound node, `output` work. but `A_3 ` layer  has multiple inbound nodes,use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead