# How to Build a Submodel in Keras' Functional API ending at a Layer of a Nested Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Usually when using the functional API to define a model one can build a submodel starting and ending at any of the original models layers. Consider, for instance, the following code:

```py
inp = tf.keras.Input((4,))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="od_1")(inp)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, name="od_2")(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="id_1")(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="od_3")(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="od_4")(y)
final_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[y])
final_model.summary()

sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[final_model.input], outputs=[final_model.get_layer("id_1").output])
```

However, when models become many and large, it can become very convenient to encapsulate some parts of the models into different python functions. These then build another model, which can be used in the functional API just like a layer. See the following example:

```py
inp_1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="id_1")(inp_1)
inner_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp_1], outputs=[x], name="inner_model")

inp_outer = tf.keras.Input((4,))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, name="od_1")(inp_outer)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, name="od_2")(y)
y = inner_model(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="od_3")(y)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name="od_4")(y)
final_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp_outer], outputs=[y])
```

This is essentially the same model as the one in the first example, just that layer 'id_1' is encapsulated in inner_model. The graph will differ due to the additional Input layer, but the computations will be the same.

Now assume I again want to access the activations of 'id_1' and henceforth build a submodel as follows:

```py
sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[final_model.input], outputs=[final_model.get_layer("inner_model").get_layer("id_1").output])
```

This will throw an exception that the Graph is not connected for the layers of the nested and the outer model:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/test_submodel_acces.py", line 35, in <module>
    sub_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[final_model.input], outputs=[final_model.get_layer("inner_model").get_layer("id_1").output])
  File "/home/***/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 146, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/***/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 167, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/***/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/***/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 320, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "/home/***/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1625, in _map_graph_network
    str(layers_with_complete_input))
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(None, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

So essentially I wonder how I can build a submodel based on a model with nested models, that has an output that previously was the layer of a nested model.

Comment: You can build you submodel using `Sequential` API from which you can access any layers without any issue. I was wondering about the fact and checked with `Sequential` submodel in a functional API based model that works fine. Still curious to know if there is any way.

Comment: Yes, I could do this for the minimal example given above, but not necessarily for any arbitrarily complex case where nested models have multi input/output etc.

Comment: completely got your point.

Comment: I could do something similar only removing the brackets from the `tf.keras.Model` call.

Answer (score 0):

According to [answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530328/cannot-obtain-the-output-of-intermediate-sub-model-layers-with-tf2-0-keras), you should replace

```
get_layer("id_1").output
```

by

```
get_layer("id_1").get_output_at(0)
```

I'm not fluent enough in keras to explain why, but this works, at least in my use cases...